# Molly in The Last Unicorn

Tags: the-last-unicorn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Role and significance of Molly Grue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15874/role-and-significance-of-molly-grue)

Most of the characters in The Last Unicorn underwent a transformation to some degree: the wizard found his power, Lir became the king, etc. What sort of transformation did Molly go through? Also, what was the purpose of her in the story? She really does not add anything (at least in my opinon).

Answer (score 0):

Molly's growth is the realization that she's not a waste! She is valuable because she motivates Schmendrick. She is the driving force that keeps the wizard working, and her faith in him is needed for him to continue the quest.

Further, she's there to feed lore to other characters.

Plus, in many ways, she's the comic relief in the story.